# Showing Text Box On Hover (In Table)

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables, onhover

I've been trying for a while now to create a text on hover in my table.
I've been trying to add it for hovering over this `<td class="text-left" id="caster_num">1</td>` but I've had no luck so far. I've been following this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp. Could someone please assist me?

*I want the text to show over the text being hovered (in this case the "1").

Thank you.

```css
body {
  background-color: #2c313a;
  font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

div.table-title {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-title h3 {
  color: #fafafa;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*** Table Styles **/

.table-fill {
  background: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation: float 5s infinite;
}

th {
  color: #D5DDE5;
  background: #1b1e24;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #9ea7af;
  border-right: 1px solid #343a45;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

th:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  color: #666B85;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);
}

tr:hover td {
  background: #4E5066;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #22262e;
}

tr:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #EBEBEB;
}

tr:nth-child(odd):hover td {
  background: #4E5066;
}

td {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-right: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}

th.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

th.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

th.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

td.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

td.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

td.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <table class="table-fill">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-left">Name</th>
          <th class="text-left">Attribute</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="table-hover">
        <tr id="caster">
          <td class="text-left">Caster</td>
          <td class="text-left" id="caster_num">1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't see any css in you question. Where do you want your text to be added, do you want pure css, 
and especially : what have you tried ? we will help you find what errors you made, but we wont code for you. also your two links are the same ;)

Comment: Okey, after your edit : i see no trace of a tooltip class or a sign that you actually tried the tutorial you linked us, it is pretty simple if you know you are doing, just add the span in your td, add the classes tooltip and tooltiptext, and the awample css, it works like a charm

Comment: @Neil Hey, sorry, didn't include it in the CSS I posted since I've tried it with many different edits, didn't know which version to upload... I tried adding the span in my TD and adding the classes but with the DIV is becomes a voodoo effect (div in table)

Comment: That was the way to go, except you replace every `div` with a `td`. don't be afraid to show us a code that doesn't work, at least we can see where you have an issue :) if your td doesn't like to be `position:relative`, you can just put the span inside a tooltip div, inside your td ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a CSS only solution but I had to modify your html a bit. Not sure if you wanted the tooltip to cover the trigger or to be positioned above it, but this example just puts the tooltip directly to the right of the trigger. You can modify to suit your needs.

If you don't want to include the extra `span`, you'll need some additional javascript to get the contents of the previous `td`.

This is all based on https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp

https://codepen.io/carbonspace/pen/rqaVzb

HTML

```
<table class="table-fill">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-left">Name</th>
      <th class="text-left">Attribute</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr id="caster">
      <td class="text-left">Caster</td>
      <td class="text-left tooltipTrigger" id="caster_num">1
        <span class="tooltip">Caster</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.tooltipTrigger .tooltip {
  display: none;
}
.tooltipTrigger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tooltipTrigger:hover .tooltip {
  display: inline;
  position: relative; /* relative to .tooltipTrigger */
  left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can hover the row and then apply some css

```
.table-fill tr #caster_num { visibility: hidden; color: transparent; }
.table-fill tr:hover #caster_num { visibility: visible; color: black; }
```

Comment: he wants a tooltip, not to hide the number, and his tutorial explains already all that is needed